# How to bridge two networks with Ubiquiti hardware?

Tags: wireless, bridge

I want to connect two networks using a wireless bridge. My networks are in different subnets and each have their own router (and DHCP server, and independent internet connection).

I tried a basic layer 2 bridge, but I can't connect to devices on the other network. I can ping both wireless devices (Ubiquiti Nanostation) from network 1.

Network 1:
Router IP: 192.168.0.1 (and DHCP server), Mask: 255.255.255.0
Nanostation IP: 192.168.0.3 (as Access Point), Mask: 255.255.255.0

Network 2:
Router IP: 192.168.1.1 (and DHCP server), Mask: 255.255.255.0
Nanostation IP: 192.168.0.4 (as Station), Mask: 255.255.255.0

Comment: Probably not really a network engineering question; perhaps should migrate to superuser.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a route, otherwise you have two networks with no reason to talk across the link, as they are different subnets, with different default gateways, and the nanostation **at** network 2 is **on** network 1. If you plug a single computer into the LAN port on that nanostation, does it connect to network 1? it should, if the link is working. But without a route, no traffic will flow.

So you need a router at each end that is capable of managing a connection to WAN and a connection to the other network. Not difficult, but not consumer-grade stuff.